# Does my fajr namaz count if I prayed 20 mins before sunrise?

Tags: salat

I have a quick question regarding about namaz timings:  Does my fajr namaz count if I prayed at 4:58 am and sunrise was at 5:18 a.m.

Comment: Prayer timing is greatly dependent on your area. But in this specific case, you are praying about 20 minutes before even time starts, than it is not valid prayer, start of time is a condition for prayer to be valid, so you should repeat your prayer.

Comment: no he is saying that he prayed fajr 20 mins before sunrise and is asking if it still valid

Comment: @ahmed i gave my opinion about same thing, and this opinion is based on something which happened to me. I prayed asar before time, because the clock i was following was about 2 hour ahead, than i consulted and got the answer that i have to repeat my prayer.

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal the point is sunrise may mean shoroq not fajr (dawn): Which means his prayer is still valid and correct.

Comment: @Medi1Saif in that case it would had been soo definite that i doubt one would have asked this, but in that case question needs to be updated. Because apparently question is asking for praying before time starts. And in that case, prayer is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Verily, As-Salaah (the prayer) is enjoined on the believers at fixed hours”

[al-Nisa’ 4:103]

The prayer brother should be offered on time depending on where you live this you can check online based on your city or based on your local mosque prayer timetable. Prayer offered before its time is not valid. However, prayer offered after its appointed time for a valid reason for example you could not pray because you were in a lesson at school is valid.

Comment: The problem with time tables is that we relay on calcualtions which are not "backed up" , for example if you use the Um-Al-Qura calcualtion methode in Europe or USA you may even pray 30-90 min. before the real time of some prayers!

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is valid.

The time for Fajr prayer lasts from the onset of the true dawn until the sun starts to rise.

> The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “The
>   time for Fajr prayer is from the breaking of dawn, so long as the sun
>   has not started to rise.” Narrated by Muslim, 612.

If a person offers this prayer during this time, he has prayed on time. Based on this, Fajr can be prayed 20 minutes before sunrise.